# ggplot : Hide geom_ribbon by default to my plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, r-plotly

I have this plot :

```
g.mean <- ggplot(df,aes(x = as.numeric(xx),y=yy,color=varc)) + 
      geom_line() +
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Born_Inf, ymax=Born_Sup, fill=varc), alpha=0.1)
```

Is there a way to hide only geom_ribbon() and print geom_line() to my graph ? I try with "legendonly" but this hide all lines ...

```
style(ggplotly(g.mean, tooltip = c("varc")), hoverinfo = "value",visible="legendonly")  #,traces = 1
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by *"hide only `geom_ribbon`"*. If you don't want `geom_ribbon` why not just remove it?

Comment: By default I would like hide geom_ribbon because varc in "fill" argument have lot of factors (10 factors). The plot is not clear with all   geom_ribbon factors. I would like to choose to print confidence interval for some factors but no by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide geom_ribbon() with argument "**traces**" in function "***style()***". For example : I have 10 factors in my varC so I have 10 lines (geom_line()) and 10 CI (geom_ribbon) : 20 items.

To hide geom_ribbon() indicates to "**traces**" 11:20 and **visible="legendonly"**.

```
style(ggplotly(g.mean, tooltip = c("varC","x","y")),
  visible="legendonly",
  hoverinfo = "value",
  traces = c((length(unique(df$varC))+1):(length(unique(df$varC))*2)))
```